# Packages are broken

Tags: package-repositories

Almost any time I try to use packages, they fail for one reason or another. I did
manage to install a package some time last year (2020) but not since.

The marmalade-repo.org has had a bad certificate for years (expired 2017 I think)
so I commented it out; my .emacs now says:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
     '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
     '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
;(add-to-list 'package-archives
;    '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
```

But any attempt at package-list-packages get the error:

```
Failed to download ‘melpa’ archive.
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80
Saving file /home/peter/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/gnu/archive-contents...
Wrote /home/peter/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/gnu/archive-contents
cond: Invalid version list ‘(8 6 -4)’
```

I'm obviously Doin' It Wrong™ but I don't understand where.
Is there a way to make packages work again?
Is there something I can do to help?

Comment: What version of emacs are you using? `M-x emacs-version` to find out.

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian. This is what comes with Mint 20.1. But packages have been flaky for years, with broken certificates and sites going offline and packages disappearing and reappearing.

Comment: Well, 26.3 _should_ work (the debian build of 26.1 certainly didn't).  What does the backtrace look like if you do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then fire `package-list-packages`?

Comment: Still experimenting. Packages work now (someone must have fixed the certificates)

Comment: Broken again: I'm getting the message "Invalid version list ‘(8 6 -4)’" when I use M-x list-packages RET

Comment: Doing M-x toggle-debug-on-error and then package-list-packages, I get 
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid version list ‘(8 6 -4)’")
  signal(error ("Invalid version list ‘(8 6 -4)’"))
  error("Invalid version list `%s'" (8 6 -4)) 
Too much to fit here so I posted it at http://silmaril.ie/downloads/backtrace

Comment: The issue is with package `mh-e` which is built-in and apparently has a broken version number (that `-4`).  Can't help much more that except to note that I have no such issue with 27.2 (but then again, I could run `list-packages` when I had 26.3 with no issues).  Sorry not to be more helpful.

Comment: Just thought, what happens if you do `M-x package-refresh-contents` before the `list-packages`?  That should refresh a stale/broken package list.

Comment: @fran-burstall Thanks for finding this. Makes no difference if I do a refresh beforehand, unfortunately. This fails in 26.3 fresh install from Mint 20.1 repos *and* in a newly-compiled-from-source 27.2. Where do I report mh-e?

Comment: Since it is built-in, I guess to the emacs bug list.  *But* I am running 27.2, built from source, and have no such issues.  For example "C-h P <RET> mh-e" works fine (and reports a version `8.6snapshot`) so I suspect that there is something odd about your setup.